# clear setTimeout inside immediately invoked functions

Tags: javascript, function, settimeout

```
 var a = function(bool){
       (function b(bool){
          if(bool === true || bool === undefined){
          console.log('running');
          setTimeout(b,50);
          }else{
           clearTimeout(b);
          }
       })();
   }
```

I've learned this was suppose to be better than `setInterval` though clearing this function does not work. I've tried break as well as return and it keeps looping through the `console.log`

Any suggestions on how to cancel this function easily?

**What I've Tried**

```
        if(bool === true || bool === undefined){
          console.log('running');
          setTimeout(b,50);
          }else{
          return;
          }

        var d;
        if(bool === true || bool === undefined){
          console.log('running');
          d=setTimeout(b,50);
          }else{
           clearTimeout(d);
          }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`clearTimeout` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.clearTimeout)) expects the "timeoutID" and NOT the function as parameter:

```
var id = setTimeout(b,50);
clearTimeout(id);
```

But when I look closer at your code, it seems that there is another problem:

```
setTimeout(b,50);
```

You are calling `b` without any parameter, so the function parameter `bool` will always be `undefined`! Try this:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    b(false);
},50);
```

Then it should only iterate once. And then you don't need to clear the timeout at all (you just stop setting new timeouts):

```
var a = function(bool){
       (function b(bool){
          if(bool === true || bool === undefined){
              console.log('running');
              setTimeout(function () {
                  var goOn = false; //<--- abort condition here
                  b(goOn);
              },50);
          }
       })();
   }
```

Now you only have to figure out what your abort condition is and bring that in, at the right place.

**EDIT** (Answer to your comment)

It seems you just want one function that starts the interval and one function that stops it. So what follows is a minimal example of such a setup (also with counting the iterations). It should be fairly easy to adapt this to your own needs.

```
var goOn = false,
    counter = 0;

function run() {
    counter++;
    if (goOn) {
        setTimeout(run, 50);
    }
}

function start() {
    counter = 0;
    goOn = true;
    run();
}

function stop() {
    goOn = false;
    console.log(counter);
}
```

Comment: yes yes yes ;) I've tried that as well. Sorry that post was the last trial I tried

Comment: Ok I see what you did there, though the problem is I don't want one iteration

Comment: Sure, but you didn't give any information on when you want this interval to end.

Comment: I am setting a code up so that `_$.steps('sec')` it progress through steps in seconds, then if they write `_$.steps('break')` or something it should stop and give them the returned steps.